# What is Tomcat Running?

Tags: java, linux, tomcat

I'm trying to see if a WAR I just built is even running inside of Tomcat (**7.0.19**). I am deploying to a linux box and so my only two options are the Tomcat admin console (web app) or, hopefully, determining webapp status through the terminal.

I already know how to get in through the console web app; I am wondering if there is any way to see the status (ACTIVE/INACTIVE/TERMINATED, etc) of deployed web apps from the terminal.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which version of Tomcat?

Comment: Tomcat places log statements on deploying or undeploying. So even logs can be of some help.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder! Please see edit to my opening sentence (in bold).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
curl --user user:pass http://localhost:8080/manager/text/list
```

It prints

```
OK - Listed applications for virtual host localhost
/manager:running:0:manager
/docs:running:0:docs
/examples:running:0:examples
/host-manager:running:0:host-manager
/myapp:running:0:myapp
```

Your user needs the `manager-script` role. Documentation: [Manager App HOW-TO, List_Currently_Deployed_Applications](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html#List_Currently_Deployed_Applications)

Answer (score 2):

[PSI-Probe](http://code.google.com/p/psi-probe/) is a great application for monitoring your applications deployed to a tomcat instance. It will tell you if an application is running or down. If the application is not deployed, it will simply not be in the list.

Comment: Great suggestion! Taking a look at it now

Comment: @javagirl I didn't say tomcat manager was worse. But PSI-Probe offers a lot of features that the manager does not.

Comment: are those features essential for @zharvey ? it's unclear from the question why usual tomcat manager does not suit his requirements

Answer (score 1):

You can probably do it using JMX. 
Find appropriate MBean that shows this information on local tomcat using regular JConsole. If you want to connect JConsole to remote you will probably have some problems with firewall, so you have other solution.

Take command line JMX client and run it on the monitored host through SSH terminal. I used the following command line JMX client: [cmdline-jmxclient-0.10.3.jar](http://crawler.archive.org/cmdline-jmxclient/downloads.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
wget http://<username>:<password>@<hostname>:<port>/manager/list -O - -q
```

(Not sure about Tomcat 7 though)